# Stop Creation of Log Analytics Workspaces

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-policy

I want to stop creation of Log Analytics workspaces, what is the best way to achieve this? can you do this via azure policies, if so how?

thank you in advance, 
Kelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the best possible way to restrict creating any resources is using azure policies. Below azure policy will help you in stopping the creation of log analytics workspace in your subscription.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Deny creating Log analytics",
        "description": "This policy denies creation of log analytics workspace.",
        "parameters": {
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this policies, but it doesnt work. In what feature this would work?

Answer (score 1):

It is also interesting to note that with the introduction of the new access control mode "Require Workspace Permissions", users can only see logs for resources that they have the correct privileges to. Therefore allowing teams to utilize a centralized Log Analytics workspace for all their logging needs